# Aplicar filtros a consulta NoSQL en MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que utiliza una base de datos NoSQL y quisiera saber cómo realizar una consulta para que filtre por el campo `source` del siguiente conjunto de datos:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f9ba45647ba23c39207e9d"),
    "ident" : "66198708-5c99-11e5-824f-00f489953837",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-09-16T18:51:49.681Z"),
    "normalized" : true,
    "payload" : {
        "pattern" : "head",
        "time" : "2015-09-16 15:52:07",
        "filename" : null,
        "source" : [
            "192.168.100.107",
            915
        ],
        "request_raw" : "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: 192.168.100.109\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nmap Scripting Engine; http://nmap.org/book/nse.html)",
        "request_url" : "/"
    },
    "channel" : "glastopf.events"
}
```

Vale aclarar, que tengo muy poca experiencia en este tipo de base de datos, el servidor de base de datos es [MongoDB v2.6.11](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si te refieres a hacer el query desde la consola de MongoDB, puedes intentar lo siguiente (estoy usando la versión `v3.2`) usando el operador de array [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all):

```
db.nombrecoleccion.find({
    'payload.source': {
        $all: ["192.168.100.107", 915]
    }
})
```

Lo que hace `$all` es obtener los documentos en donde el valor del campo es un `array` que contiene los elementos especificados.

Más ejemplos:

- Buscar el primer elemento del `array`:

  ```
  db.nombrecoleccion.find({
      'payload.source.0': "192.168.100.107"
  })
  ```
- Buscar el segundo elemento y que sea mayor que `900`:

  ```
  db.nombrecoleccion.find({
      'payload.source.1': {$gt: 900}
  })
  ```
- Buscar mezclando las dos condiciones anteriores:

  ```
  db.nombrecoleccion.find({
      'payload.source.0': "192.168.100.107",
      'payload.source.1': {$gt: 900}
  })
  ```
- Buscar en donde el primer elemento sea igual a cualquiera de los valores en un array (usando el operador [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)):

  ```
  db.nombrecoleccion.find({
      'payload.source.0': {
          $in: [
              "192.168.100.105", 
              "192.168.100.107", 
              "192.168.100.109"
           ]
      }
  })
  ```

Puedes consultar otros operadores para `array` en [Query Operator Array](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-array/)

Comment: En base a tu respuesta Cesar voy a editar la pregunta, ya que no sabia que era dependiente de la versión , actualmente tengo la 2.6.11 . Saludos

Comment: @Santi92 según veo en la documentación del 2.6, la función es la misma. Has intentado correr el query?

Comment: no me ha funcionado, además el segundo elemento no me interesa por lo que podría ser cualquiera. la consulta me debería devolver todos las filas  que tengan esa IP

Comment: @Santi92, has visto mi actualización? El primer ejemplo seguro te sirve

Comment: Ahora si funciona, muchas gracias